# DataGridView System.FormatException: Value '' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, datagridview

Datagridview has several comboboxes with fixed items

I will create a table and export it to excel, when exporting to excel I will get the combobox Id

I made the settings like this but I get this error when selecting an item from the combobox

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataSet1.Tables["Sehir"].Rows.Add(34, "İstanbul");
        dataSet1.Tables["Sehir"].Rows.Add(6, "Ankara");
        dataSet1.Tables["Sehir"].Rows.Add(7, "Antalya");
        dataSet1.Tables["Sehir"].Rows.Add(38, "Kayseri");
        dataSet1.Tables["Sehir"].Rows.Add(58, "Sivas");
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: First, seeing your code that exports to Excel would help. Then I guess you just need to export a string, so replace `ID` by `ID.ToString()`

Comment: that's not the problem right now, I get this error when selecting an item from the combobox

Comment: then show a bit of code at least. And explain where concretely you have the error

Comment: @Siegfried.V  I get this error when selecting an item from the combobox